# Why is useEffect running so many times when it shouldn't?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mouseclick-event

I've set up a map with terrain on it. I track clicks and mouseovers. However, useEffect seems to be firing off despite the conditions I've given it. I have 12 total terrain pieces on the map. Everything works as I'd like it to but this rogue behavior baffles me and I don't want it to be the cause to any problems down the road. Thank you for your time!

Screenshot of what is logged after **one** click on a **terrain** :
https://i.gyazo.com/5ac7ff913a0e29c9539090325a0abe9b.png

Code:

````
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRef } from "react"
import { useEffect } from "react"

import BriefTerrainInfo from "./BriefTerrainInfo"
import DetailedTerrainInfo from "./DetailedTerrainInfo"


export default function Terrain({ src, className, id, dataDetailed, dataBrief }) {

    //HANDLING TERRAIN CLICK
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
    let terrainRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)

        return () => { document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler) }
    }, [])

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        if (terrainRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
            console.log('inside')
            setIsClicked(prevClicked => !prevClicked)

        } else {
            console.log('outside')
            setIsClicked(false)

        }
    }


    //HANDLING TERRAIN MOUSEOVER
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverHandler)

        return () => { document.removeEventListener('mouseover', hoverHandler) }
    }, [])

    const hoverHandler = (e) => {
        if (terrainRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
            setIsHovered(true)
        } else {
            setIsHovered(false)
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className={className} id={id}>
            <img src={src} ref={terrainRef} ></img>
            {isHovered && <BriefTerrainInfo dataBrief={dataBrief} />}
            {isClicked && <DetailedTerrainInfo dataDetailed={dataDetailed} />}
        </div>
    )
}```

UPDATE 01: I've updated the code and now there are no hordes of useEffects firing off due to the onClick being moved onto the Terrain component DIV. However, I did lose the click inside/outside dynamic functionality that it gave me. Here's a github link to the full app: https://github.com/Baleandor/WAHA-Game . The fight continues.
````

Comment: 12 terrain components on the map means 12 click handlers have been added to the document, it's not "rogue behavior" as you've stated. Maybe move the click handler to a parent component?

Comment: Thanks for the input. That sounds like a good call! I'll work on it ASAP.

Comment: If you want each Terrain piece to have its own click handler, your original code is not a problem. You do click outside 11 pieces and inside one.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I see. So there was no point in me worrying over the 11 extra clicks then?